# Displaying items from a JSON array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I want to create a favourites page, where people can favourite and office and it then gets displayed in a favourites page.

This is my controller that i am using to try and display the items which are in the variable 'd'.

```
.controller('FavCtrl', function($scope, $window, $http){

var flag = false;
var b = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
console.log(b);

$scope.ifinfav = function(d){
  if (b.indexOf(d) !== -1){
    var flag = true;
    console.log(flag);
    return flag;
  }
}

})
```

This is the favourites page i want to output the items to. I am trying to use ng-class to display only the favourites that are stored in the localstorage by passing in the id of the JSON item and returning if its true or false. If the id is in the localstorage then it should output that item on the page but i am not sure where to go from here.

```
<ion-view view-title="Favourites">
    <ion-content ng-controller="APICtrl">
        <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-class="ifinfav(office.id)" id="fav" class="item-icon-right" collection-repeat="office in offices" ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-click="openModal(office.id); lastview(office.id);">
            <!-- <p>{{office.id}}</p> -->
            <p id="details">{{office.LocAddressLine1 + ", " + office.LocAddressLine2 + ", " + office.LocCity + ", " + office.LocCountryDescription + ", " + office.LocZipPostalCode}}</p>
            <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': liked, 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !liked}" ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
        </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle or codepen please?

Comment: don't know if thats the issue cause i just quickly read over it: in your `ifinfav` function you're assigning `true` to your `scope.flag` property, but return the variable `flag` which is never changed (and not part of your `scope`). you should read up about the basics of js and angularjs first because your code implies that you didn't.